# Some hashtable problems. Removing objects from the hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm having some problems removing clients from a channellist.

This is the code i have at the moment:

**Serverside:**

```
private Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>> channels = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    public synchronized void logMeOut(String username) throws RemoteException {
        for(Client c : clients){
            if(c.findName().equals(username)){
                clients.remove(c);
                disconnectAllChans(username);
                System.out.println(username + " removed from clientlist.");
            }
        }
        updateJListForOnlineUsers(); //Callback for other clients to update the userlist.
    }

  public void disconnectAllChans(String username) throws RemoteException{
    for(Enumeration e = channels.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();){
        if(channels.contains(username)){
            channels.remove(username);
        }
    }
    updateJListForUsersInChannel();
    System.out.println("User " + username + " left all channel");
}
```

I have tried both if(channels.contains(username), and containsKey. None of them seems to do the work. When i leave the server, which runs the logout method, the client just hangs. I'm guessing its going on a foreverloop in that Enumeration loop.

EDIT: The client only hangs IF it has joined a channel. If the channellist for a user is empty, it quits right away.

Any ideas how the code should look?

**

### Solution:

**

So yeah, i figured it out, but i wouldn't have without you guys. Thanks

I just ran the disconnectmethod inside the disconnect all channels method which brainzzy posted. Heres the result:

```
@Override
public void disconnectChannel(String username, String channel) throws RemoteException{
    if(isUserInChannelX(username, channel)){
        channels.get(channel).remove(username);
        String message = "User " + username + " left the channel.";
        notifySelf(username, " You have left the channel " + channel);
        notifyChannelSystem(channel, "SYSTEM", message);
        updateJListForActiveChannels();
        if(channels.get(channel).isEmpty()){
            channels.remove(channel);
        } 
    }
}

public void disconnectAllChans(String username) throws RemoteException{
    for (String channel : channels.keySet()) {
    ArrayList<String> members = channels.get(channel);
        if (members.contains(username)) {
            disconnectChannel(username, channel);
            System.out.println("User " + username + " left channel " + channel);
        }
    }
    updateJListForUsersInChannel();
}
```

I feel kinda stupid ^^ Thanks people!

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger on your code?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't help me too much tbh :(

Comment: it seems like the e.hasMoreElements() go on forever.

Comment: Note: You probably shouldn't be using a `Hashtable`. If don't need thread safety you should be using a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), and if you do need thread safety you should be using a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: e.hasMoreElements returns true every time, and return contains() return false. But, the e.hasMoreElements shouldn't find more channels than the user is connected to..

Comment: @Jeffrey yeah, i've heard that already, but i don't know how to change it tbh. I'm scared that would take alot of work with my code all over

Comment: @sindrem I dont see you using the 'e' inside the loop. Shouldn't you be using that if you have put a loop over the elements of the channel? The loop doesn't seem to end

Comment: Of course it does. You need to call `e.nextElement()` otherwise `e.hasMoreElements()` will go on forever. No channels means `e.hasMoreElements()` will return false even without calling `e.nextElement()` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the for with a foreach loop, makes it harder to make infinite loop errors like you've got yourself into by not handling the enumerator correctly:

```
for (String channel : channels.keySet()) {
    ArrayList<String> members = channels.get(channel);
    if (members.contains(username)) {
        members.remove(username);
    }
}
```

I think that'll do what you want it to.

Comment: It kinda work it seems, except that some methods after reconnecting the server seems a bit off. When i enter the same channel, which i've been in before disconnecting, it does not get updated in my JList. However, if i join a channel i've been in before disconnecting, and then connects a couple of more random channels, they all get updated at the same time..

Comment: Does that method really remove any channels from the channels hashtable, or just the members array? I'm confused. i gotta do some systemoutprint ^^

Comment: So, if i use this method my join method will print out "user connected to (channel)", but the jList refuses to update after joining a channel. If i leave all channels manually before quitting, the Jlist does work. what the hell ;(

Comment: It removes a given username from any of the channels (assuming the ArrayList<String> is a list of users in the given channel).

Comment: Would you mind checking out this thread as well? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977241/problems-updating-my-jlist-for-active-channels

Answer (score 5):

You have an infinite loop in your code:

```
for(Enumeration e = channels.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();){
    if(channels.contains(username)){
        channels.remove(username);
    }
}
```

You never take an element off Enumeration `e`, so `e.hasMoreElements` will always return true. You probably want something more like this:

```
ArrayList<String> channel = null;
for(Enumeration e = channels.elements(); e.hasMoreElements(); channel = e.nextElement()){
    if(channel.contains(username)){
        channel.remove(username);
    }
}
```

As a side note, you're going to run into concurrent modification errors with your current code.

Comment: hm, how should i fix that?

Could i use something like this?

    `Enumeration k = channels.keys();
        while(k.hasMoreElements()){
            if(channels.contains(username)){
                channels.remove(username);
            }
        }`

Comment: use `channels.entrySet().iterator()` and call `Iterator.remove` on matches.

Comment: What is the relationship between 'username' and channels? Sounds like `channels` is actually a map keyed on username?

Comment: The username is inside a channel, if that explains it. Tbh, i would love to find a better solution, but this is the only thing i got working, after SEVERAL hours

I did paste the Hashtable in my first post, which kinda explains it i guess

Comment: OK, so you have a list of users for each channel? The naming of your identifiers might require some rethinking. `usersInChannels`?

Comment: Ok, I adjusted my answer slightly based on your feedback. Try the code out and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: @Perception I don't have any Channels class tho. What should i do then?

Comment: @sindrem - I see you are using ArrayList<String> as definition of a channel. Use that instead of `Channel` (code updated).

Comment: posted my solution above. Thanks everyone, especially you @Perception